# Kendo grid's column headers do not scale correctly

Tags: css, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Kendo grid's column headers does not scale correctly, eg. when browser has large/small resolution. You can reproduce it easily by zooming the browser. See figure below.
[image]

Is this a bug and does it have any work arounds?

Screenshot was taken from Telerik's Kendo grid example:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

Comment: Which browser / OS do you use?

Comment: I've used Chrome and Firefox (Windows 7). They both produce the same result.

Comment: Suggest to use some inspect tool to check which css declarations affects to column headers.

Comment: Done that, but haven't found solution yet.

Comment: Is your browser scaling at 100%? I've been able to reproduce it but only if I rescale browser content but not if it is at 100%.

Comment: In my browser it does not scale perfectly at any %-scaling. Also 100% scales it a little bit wrong.

Comment: I've worked with kendo grids since long time and I've never seen bug like that if you not change anything in css and not set columns widths by jquery. The link you pasted it's basic kendo grid so it's the simplest one. Do you have the latest version of your browsers? Can you check `#grid .k-grid-header` padding-right value? It should be set at 17px. Then `.k-grid-header table` width and `.k-grid-content table` width should be equal and have the same width value in each `colgroup col`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug. The column header only seems to be off-scale when I zoom-in (110% or more scales) on the grid.

The grid will again be in-scale if I refresh the page at any % scales.